# Cabrera Mott Oxidation Theory

Tags: material-science

For oxidation of aluminum, the Cabrera Mott Oxidation theory states that "oxygen is not dissolvable in aluminum oxide" and that Al$^{3+}$ ions migrate to thicken the oxide. My questions are, 1. how does a metal ion migrate (aren't metals arranged in a lattice, not as free ions?) and 2. how does one know if oxygen is not dissolvable in aluminum oxide or not? Any answers or relevant references would much be appreciated!